# php foreach loop giving only 1 result from the array

Tags: php, arrays, csv, foreach

I have a [csv file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/mei6ambewivz5o6/stores.csv?dl=0) containing attributes of the stores (id, name, category, featured, etc) to be displayed in a project. For now I need to display an array of featured stores with the condition 'featured'='TRUE'. There are [10 results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZhicR.png).

Here's the code to read the file and save the data as an associative array

```
  function read_all_stores() {
  $file_name = 'csv_files/stores.csv';
  $fp = fopen($file_name, 'r');
  $first = fgetcsv($fp); // get the first row aka headlines of the file
  $stores = [];
  while ($row = fgetcsv($fp)) {
    $i = 0;
    $store = [];
    foreach ($first as $col_name) {
      $store[$col_name] =  $row[$i];
      $i++;
    }
    $stores[] = $store;
  }
  return $stores;
}
```

[sample result of the first 5 stores](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KM6we.png)

Now I want to display only the stores that has attribute featured = 'TRUE'. I tried this code:

```
function get_store() {
    $stores = read_all_stores();
    $feature = [];
    foreach ($stores as $s) {
      while ($s['featured'] == 'TRUE') {
        $feature[] = $s;
        return $feature;
      }
    }
    return false;
  }
```

But it only returns [one result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xKw7T.png).

I tried removing the single quotation mark but it seems to only accept the 'TRUE' value as string instead of boolean. How can I fix this foreach loop??

Comment: Is this line causing the problem? `$stores[] = $store;`. Also, in `get_store` method you are returning as soon as there is a match. I think you should add all of the matched ones into an array and then return at the end of the method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that as soon as you find a matching result: `$s['featured'] == 'TRUE'`, you return it: `return $feature;`. Instead, you need to process *all* values in `$stores` before returning your result. If there are matching stores (`count($feature)` is non-zero i.e. *truthy*), return them, otherwise return false.

```php
function get_store() {
    $stores = read_all_stores();
    $feature = [];
    foreach ($stores as $s) {
        if ($s['featured'] == 'TRUE') {
            $feature[] = $s;
        }
    }
    return count($feature) ? $feature : false;
}
```

Comment: How is this different from the comment added before?

Comment: @fiveelements comments are not answers. You had the option to add an answer but chose to make a comment which really didn't provide much detail. I gave OP an answer to their question.

Answer (score 0):

Two problems in your code:

1. In `get_store()` method you are returning as soon as you find a match. Instead you should add all the matched ones and then return at the end.
2. For checking a match you should use `if` instead of `while`

Here is the modified version of your code:

```
<?php
function read_all_stores() {
    $file_name = 'stores.csv';
    $fp = fopen($file_name, 'r');
    $first = fgetcsv($fp); // get the first row aka headlines of the file
    $stores = [];
    while ($row = fgetcsv($fp)) {
        $i = 0;
        $store = [];
        foreach ($first as $col_name) {
        $store[$col_name] =  $row[$i];
        $i++;
        }
        $stores[] = $store;
    }
    return $stores;
}
function get_store() {
    $stores = read_all_stores();
    $feature = [];
    foreach ($stores as $s) {
        if ($s['featured'] == 'TRUE') {
        $feature[] = $s;
        }
    }
    return $feature;
}

echo count(get_store());
```

Comment: thank you it works now!! also in which situation should i use while and if?