# php display array results by first letter from select option

Tags: php, html, arrays, select

I have an array containing attributes of each store (this is just the first few kv pairs, there're 100 in total)

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [name] => 21st Century Fox 3
            [category_id] => 1
            [created_time] => 2018-06-03 11:01:54Z
            [featured] => FALSE
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [name] => 21st Century Fox 5
            [category_id] => 1
            [created_time] => 2021-05-02 11:22:04Z
            [featured] => FALSE
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [name] => Carrefour 3
            [category_id] => 1
            [created_time] => 2018-10-20 22:28:48Z
            [featured] => FALSE
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 4
            [name] => Coca-Cola Company 2
            [category_id] => 1
            [created_time] => 2020-09-19 19:14:29Z
            [featured] => FALSE
        )
    [4] => Array
        (
            [id] => 5
            [name] => Erickson
            [category_id] => 1
            [created_time] => 2021-01-23 00:58:07Z
            [featured] => FALSE
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [id] => 6
            [name] => Boeing 1
            [category_id] => 2
            [created_time] => 2019-11-26 11:17:17Z
            [featured] => FALSE
        )
```

and a select box (attribute name="letter-start") with each option as a character in the alphabet.

The goal is when I choose from the select box, it will display only the stores whose names are similar to that letter from the select option. For example, I choose "A" and it will only display the stores with [name] starting with A:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 12
            [name] => AECOM 1
            [category_id] => 3
            [created_time] => 2020-12-29 12:57:25Z
            [featured] => FALSE
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 20
            [name] => Areon Impex 1
            [category_id] => 3
            [created_time] => 2019-11-09 22:43:32Z
            [featured] => TRUE
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 21
            [name] => Amazon.com 2
            [category_id] => 4
            [created_time] => 2019-10-19 21:30:39Z
            [featured] => FALSE
        )
```

Here's what I tried:

```
echo "<div class=\"flex-container\">";
$selected = $_GET['first-letter'];
foreach ($stores as $s) {
  if ($selected === $s['name'][0]) {
  $id = $s['id'];
  $name = $s['name'];
  //display the stores
  echo "<div class=\"item\"><a href=\"store-home.php?id=$id\"><div class=\"image\"><img src=\"images/store.png\" alt=\"a store\"></div><h3 class=\"name\">$name</h3></a></div>";
  }
}
echo "</div>";
```

But it doesn't receive the $_GET or $_POST value. You can refer to the full store list [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/mei6ambewivz5o6/stores.csv?dl=0) and the function to read and store all data into array $stores [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67666461/php-foreach-loop-giving-only-1-result-from-the-array).

Edit: here's the select box

```
<form action="browse-store-1.php">
 <label for="letter-start">Store names start with letter </label>
 <select id="letter-start" name="letter-start">
  <option id="all">All</option>
  <option id="#" value="#">#</option>
  <option id="a" value="A">A</option>
  <option id="b" value="B">B</option>
  <option id="c" value="C">C</option>
  <option id="d" value="D">D</option>
  <option id="e" value="E">E</option>
  <option id="f" value="F">F</option>
  <option id="g" value="G">G</option>
  <option id="h" value="H">H</option>
  <option id="i" value="I">I</option>
  <option id="j" value="J">J</option>
  <option id="k" value="K">K</option>
  <option id="l" value="L">L</option>
  <option id="m" value="M">M</option>
  <option id="n" value="N">N</option>
  <option id="o" value="O">O</option>
  <option id="p" value="P">P</option>
  <option id="q" value="Q">Q</option>
  <option id="r" value="R">R</option>
  <option id="s" value="S">S</option>
  <option id="t" value="T">T</option>
  <option id="u" value="U">U</option>
  <option id="v" value="V">V</option>
  <option id="w" value="W">W</option>
  <option id="x" value="X">X</option>
  <option id="y" value="Y">Y</option>
  <option id="z" value="Z">Z</option>
 </select>
</form>
```

Comment: what exactly do you mean when you say: _"But it doesn't receive the $_GET or $_POST value."_ ?

Comment: @berend I tried to echo a sentence when $_GET['first-letter'] receives a value yet nothing appeared. so I assumed that the selection did not provide any value

Comment: `when I choose from the select box, it will display`  How do you fetch the data ?. Share that code

Comment: @IndraKumarS I'm quite new to php, besides setting method="get" and name="first-letter" I don't understand much what to do next with the form

Comment: Share that form Please

Comment: @IndraKumarS edited it to the post!!

Comment: @treepl  name seems to be `letter-start` But you are accessing as `$_GET['first-letter']`

Comment: oh my bad, it was the name from my draft, it's still letter-start in the official one

Comment: have you tried submitting your form? e.g. `<input type="submit" name="submit">`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to submit your form for it to get processed...

> elements of type submit are rendered as buttons. When the
> click event occurs (typically because the user clicked the button),
> the user agent attempts to submit the form to the server.
> source: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/submit)

Form with a submit button:

```
<form method="get" action="browse-store-1.php">
 <label for="letter-start">Store names start with letter </label>
 <select id="letter-start" name="letter-start">
  <option id="all">All</option>
  <option id="#" value="#">#</option>
  <option id="a" value="A">A</option>
  <option id="b" value="B">B</option>
  <option id="c" value="C">C</option>
...
  <option id="z" value="Z">Z</option>
 </select>
 <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

Form processing in `browse-store-1.php`:

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['submit'])) {
    echo "<div class=\"flex-container\">";
    $selected = $_GET['letter-start'];
    foreach ($stores as $s) {
        if ($selected === $s['name'][0]) {
            $id = $s['id'];
            $name = $s['name'];
            //display the stores
            echo "<div class=\"item\"><a href=\"store-home.php?id=$id\"><div class=\"image\"><img src=\"images/store.png\" alt=\"a store\"></div><h3 class=\"name\">$name</h3></a></div>";
        }
    }
}
```